# How can I insert a record into the db with sails-postgresql waterline ORM

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails js with the sails-postgresql adapter

I receive the following error when trying to insert a record into the database.

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
at Function.keys (native)
at __CREATE__ (/home/user123/aoresources/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:337:16)
```

config/models.js:

```
module.exports.models = {
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,

    connection: 'postgresql',
    migrate: 'safe',
    autoPK: false
};
```

Table:

```
create table if not exists users (
    id varchar(50) not null primary key,
    email varchar(254) not null
);
```

User.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }
}
```

Insert code:

```
User.create({id: 'test', email:'something'}).exec(function createCB(err,created){});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model `User.js`, add the following line:
`tableName: "users"`.

So, your `User.js` will look like:

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: "users",
    attributes: {
        email: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't provide the `tableName` property, `Waterline` automatically takes the `Model's` identity as the Table name (`User`), but since you do not have a table named `User` (but `users`), this error occurs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah this is what it was. I had tried it before and it didn't work, but that's because I went full retard and put the tableName inside my attributes object, lol.